# JQuery load Javascript on demand

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I know it already with several post about it, I read them all. 
I have an application that uses jquery tabs. In the first tab view I simply text that is displayed is not editable. In the second tab edict when click it should display the text in an editor, but the problem that I often editor appears and sometimes not.

here is my code:

```
$ ('# edita'). click (function () {
     $. getScript ("script / froala_editor.min.js", function () {
          $('#edit').editable({inlineMode: false});
     }, false); 
})
```

;

When the editor works there this in the console:
Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://xxxx.com/img/preloader.gif".

Comment: What is the dot doing in `. $ ('# edit')`?

Comment: Sorry it is : $('#edit').editable({inlineMode: false});

Comment: Update the question with that and define your issues with more clarity.

Comment: "*often editor appears and sometimes not*" sounds very strange. Can you try to find a pattern *when* it works and when it doesn't?

Comment: I know this is really weird, it's been days since I am trying to understand. 
Sometimes the editor is displayed in the first click, but other times I have to click several times to make display. When the editor works there this in the console: Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://xxxx.com/img/preloader.gif".

Comment: From what is inferable from the question, would it not be better to include your script in the parent document as per a normal script and then at the time of `click` you then trigger the function you wish to call from the script. This is a much better way than calling a document in with `$getscript` as per a button click, for efficiency reasons.

Comment: Why your website is Latin music? you speak Spanish Daniel Lisik

Comment: @Vargas no I don't speak Spanish. I did the site for a friend :)

Comment: Is that one of you can help me, I am ready to give access, I know it's risky, but I can not find a solution.